# Windows Form. New value of BindingSource filter uncheck all checked rows from the checkbox column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview, bindingsource

I have DataGrid and BindingSource connected with that DataGrid. One of the column in DataGrid is checkbox column.
My problem is that all rows are unchecked after change/apply new filter value on the BindingSource.
I wanna that my previous checked rows stay check.

Is it a possible without remembering checked rows and check them again after new filtering?

Comment: Do you mean **`DataGrid`**?

Comment: Yes, I thought on DataGrid.

Comment: Problem was that DataSource which is connected to the DataGrid do not contains information about checkbox in its collection. Rows in DataGrid are added dynamically, and some other method adds checkbox for every row and those two process are separate. That couse that I am loosing information about checkbox status. I need to save information in some other collection and bring it back after filter redraws all rows again.